# MySQL - large tables and innodb Buffer Pool Size

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a busy database, which is beginning to get a little laggy at times.

The database has a number of small tables holding around 4 gig of data. This I can make fit into the buffer pool size which I understand is good.

However, I also have several bigger tables, mainly used for logging and graph data, which adds up to around 70 gig. This doesn't fit into the buffer pool size.

I am considering storing the log data into text files rather than the database. Would this noticeably improve things? or should I be looking elsewhere for improving performance.

Comment: Have you tried adding indexes to the tables? for matching index?

Comment: Yes, virtually all my queries use indexes.

Comment: You should probably store log information somewhere else and not in MySQL (NoSQL is a really good fit for this particular case). There's also an option to use `ARCHIVE` engine for these log tables, which is probably a better option than storing them to text files.

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate NoSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with terabyte table on a 16GB machine.  It worked fine.  However, the application did not need to scan the entire terabyte.

It depends on what the "working set" is.  And how often you query the table(s).  And whether you are asking for one row via a good index, or a million rows.

Don't throw out MySQL until you have presented to us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECTs` in question.  With those we may be able to advise on

- What index(es) to add.
- How to rewrite your queries to make them sufficiently efficient.
- Or, maybe, tell you that you have an intractable problem.

One performance-killer in this context is `UUIDs`.